# LWC Too Many DML Statements 1

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, wire

I am attempting to write a Quick Action that is a LWC that will validate if a quote can be submitted for approval. If there is a validation it will return a string and display it on the screen, it no validation it should submit record into approval flow and return a string and display. When kicking off the approval flow I get the error of To Many DML Statements 1. I have read that it is because I am either using @wire or (cacheable=true). If I take (cacheable=true) away the string will not be returned and nothing will display. How should the below be handled?

HTML

```
<template>

    <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
        <pre>{somethingReturned.data}</pre>
    </div>
   
</template>
```

Javascript

```
 import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
 import ValidateQuoteForApproval from 
 '@salesforce/apex/clsSubmitToOrderLWC.ValidateQuoteForApproval';
 export default class TestQuickAction extends LightningElement {
@api recordId;



//@wire must be used to call the method. 
@wire(ValidateQuoteForApproval, {idQuote:'$recordId' })
somethingReturned;



//API Invoke is used to display the Quick action 
@api invoke() {

    somethingReturned
 }
 }
```

Apex

```
public with sharing class clsSubmitToOrderLWC {

@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static String ValidateQuoteForApproval(Id idQuote) {
boolean blnError = False;
String strErrorMessage = '';

system.debug(logginglevel.debug, 'Start ValidateQuoteForApproval          ' + idQuote);

  
SBQQ__Quote__c soQuote = [Select Id, SBQQ__LineItemCount__c, Special_Lines_Roll_UP__c
From SBQQ__Quote__c 
     Where Id = : idQuote];

 system.debug(logginglevel.debug, 'ValidateQuoteForApproval' +  soQuote);

If(soQuote.SBQQ__LineItemCount__c == 0){
strErrorMessage = strErrorMessage +  'Wait a Second! This Particular Quote has no Quote Line items \n'; 
   blnError = True;
}

If(soQuote.Special_Lines_Roll_UP__c >= 0){
    blnError = True;  
    strErrorMessage = strErrorMessage +  'Wait a Second! This Particular Quote has some Special line items which are rejected.'; 
}

If(blnError == True){
    Return strErrorMessage;
}Else{

        Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req1 = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
        req1.setComments('');
        req1.setObjectId(soQuote.id);
        Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(req1);
        Return 'Quote has been submitted for Approval'; 
        
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Not a duplicate, as this is more specific and answers even include crucial additional info on calling the class from lwc imperitively.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot perform a DML statement within `cacheable=true` as you noted. If you added a debug log, you'd notice the following under `LIMIT_USAGE`

`Number of DML statements: 1 out of 0 * CLOSE TO LIMIT`

This is by design.

In your case, and when working with LWC, you should always take a look to see if there's any provided wire adapters that can handle the action before jumping into apex.

It seems you're doing two things:

1. Querying the record you're on to do some validation checks
2. The approval process.

[getRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_wire_adapters_record) is the perfect adapter for the first step so you can quickly validate data. I'll also throw out that the [createRecord](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.data_salesforce_write) is also very helpful, although won't work with your use case of processing an approval so you'll have to set `@cacheable=false` and call the apex method [imperatively](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.apex_call_imperative).

```
const FIELDS = ['SBQQ__Quote__c.SBQQ__LineItemCount__c','SBQQ__Quote__c.Special_Lines_Roll_UP__c'];

export default class TestQuickAction extends LightningElement {
    quote;

    @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS })
    wiredRecord({ error, data }) {
        if(data) {
            this.quote = data;
            if(this.quote.fields.SBQQ__LineItemCount__c == 0){
                //handle displaying error toast message
            }

            // after all validations pass, I'd suggest renaming method to do 
            //what it now does without validations
            CreateQuoteApproval, ({idQuote:'$recordId' })
                .then(result => {
                 //process success toast
                 })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

When `@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)` is specified, you are not allowed any kind of operation that affects the database, including submitting for approval. This is because a repeated request won't have the same effect (it is not [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence)). You must specify `cacheable=false` in order to make your code work as you expect. That said, you also can't use `cacheable=false` with `@wire` methods. You will need to [call your Apex code imperatively](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/apex_call_imperative).

```
@api async invoke() {
  let result = await ValidateQuoteForApproval({idQuote: this.recordId});
}
```

Comment: When I try this way it gives syntax error of unexpected reserved word await.

Comment: @CodeMonger Yeah, I forgot the async keyword. Try my edit.

Comment: Any idea why I still get the error with cacheable=false? I'm doing a callout prior to the dml. Is that implicitly reactivating cacheable?

Comment: @Schnaps No, that wouldn't be the case--you're allowed callouts before DML operations, but you're not allowed DML before callouts. We'd need to see more complete code to figure out your circumstance. If you care to share, I'll be happy to take a look at it for you.

Comment: @sfdfox: As usual you're faster in replying than SF in giving me a clean cache. Issue vanished. I even do 'empty cache and force reload' in my browsers F12, but Salesforce seems to cache past that sometimes. All as expected now.