# wire decorator info to showToastEvent

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

Hi everybody I am creating a LWC form component I am only asking to the user a String and then I pass his information to a apex class through the wire decorator. the info that the apex class returns me is the Id of the created record because I want to use the NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl and ShowToastEvent to show the url of the new record. But when I am going to use the form in Salesforce in the google console shows me that the variable where I am storing the info from the wire does not exist when I have declared it.

My apex class .cls

```
    public with sharing class UAN_MiEntregable {
    //@AuraEnabled permite especificar que este metodo se va a llamar desde un componente LWC
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static Id createNewRecord(string nombreDeCompanero){
    Mi_entregable__c nuevoEntregable = new Mi_entregable__c();
    List<Mi_entregable__c> lista = new List<Mi_entregable__c>();

    nuevoEntregable.NombreCompanero__c = nombreDeCompanero;
    lista.add(nuevoEntregable);

    try{
        insert lista;
        return nuevoEntregable.Id;
    }catch(Exception ex) {
        throw new AuraHandledException(ex.getMessage());
    }

}
```

My .js

```
    idEntregable;
        @wire(createNewRecord, {nombreDeCompanero: '$nombreCompanero'})
    wiredInfo({ error, data }) {
        if (data) {
            this.idEntregable = data;
        }
    }

createNewRecord(){
    console.log(idEntregable.id);
    this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
        type: 'standard__recordPage',
        attributes: {
            recordId: idEntregable.id ,
            actionName: 'view',
        },
    }).then( url =>{
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Success',
                message: 'Actividad creada con éxito accede a ella desde aquí -->: {0}',
                messageData: [{
                    url,
                    label: 'here'
                },]
            })
        );
    })

}
```

I don´t know where is my mistake. Could anybody tell me? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have in your component is:-

- You have defined **@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)** in your apex method named createNewRecord. The createNewRecord method is inserting a record and hence it will throw **Too many dml statement** error.
- You can catch this error in your lwc using below piece of code:-

  ```
   @wire(createNewRecord, {nombreDeCompanero: '$nombreCompanero'})
    wiredInfo({ error, data }) {
       if (data) {
           this.idEntregable = data;
       }else if(error){
           console.log(error);
       }
   }
  ```
- To fix the issue, use imperative way of calling the apex method. Make sure apex method is without **cacheable=true** as wire will always require **@auraEnabled(cacheable=true)**. check this example:-[Imperative way of calling apex](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/main/force-app/main/default/lwc/apexImperativeMethod/apexImperativeMethod.js)

You can get more info [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/348284/lwc-too-many-dml-statements-1)

> EDIT

- Another issue is you are using below line in your code:-

  console.log(idEntregable.id);

which is wrong as it should be `console.log(this.idEntregable);`

- So basically, You need to reference the properties using **this**. Also, you are returning an Id, so `this.idEntregable` will have the id by default, so need to use `this.idEntregable.Id`.

So your code should be like this:-

```
createNewRecord(){
    console.log(this.idEntregable);
    this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
        type: 'standard__recordPage',
        attributes: {
            recordId: this.idEntregable ,
            actionName: 'view',
        },
    }).then( url =>{
        this.dispatchEvent(
            new ShowToastEvent({
                title: 'Success',
                message: 'Actividad creada con éxito accede a ella desde aquí -->: {0}',
                messageData: [{
                    url,
                    label: 'here'
                },]
            })
        );
    })

}
```

Comment: Hi @sanketkumar I tried what you said I console log the error but it does not appear in my VSCode and second when I deleted the 'cacheable=true' the google console told me to add what I deleted the error said: "Apex methods that are to be cached must be marked as @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)". I think this didn´t work

Comment: Just remove cacheable=true, do not remove @AuraEnabled

Comment: Hi @sanketkumar yeah that is what I did.

Comment: Please see the edited answer i have posted.

Comment: I have problems to share the screenshot

Comment: Please use the imperative way of caling apex in your lwc. It will fix your issue.